# Error-Failed version compatibility check with elasticsearch: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Please help me with setting up elastic agent container!
I got below error when I used podman run command followed:

**Error-Failed version compatibility check with elasticsearch: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority**

`podman run --privileged -e FLEET_SERVER_ENABLE=1 -e FLEET_SERVER ELASTICSEARCH_HOST="https://xyz:9200" -e KIBANA_FLEET_HOST="http://xyz:5601/" -e KIBANA_FLEET_USERNAME="elastic" -e KIBANA FLEET PASSWORD="<password>" -e FLEET SERVER SERVICE TOKEN="**********IUQ==" -e FLEET_SERVER_POLICY_ID= *******-bb19e9cf" -e FLEET_SERVER_ES_CA= "/local/server/path/to/volumes/certs/http_ca.crt" -e INSECURE=true -p 8220:8220 imageID`

My elasticsearch and kibana are working perfectly accessible at respectively where xyz is name of self hosted server name where I am working.

`https://xyz:9200 http://xyz:5601`

Below is my elasticsearch.yml

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
 
xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true
 
xpack.security.http.ssl:
      enabled: true
      keystore.path: certs/http.p12
 
#Enable encryption and mutual authentication between cluster nodes
 
xpack.security.transport.ssl:
      enabled: true
      verification mode: certificate
      keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
      truststore.path: certs/transport.p12
```

Following are podman commands to start elasticsearch and kibana

```
podman run -e ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4g-Xmx4g" --name kib01 --net host -p 5601:5601 imageID
podman run -e ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4g-Xmx4g" --name kib01 --net host -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" -it imageID
```

I am using 8.11.1 version images
For my elasticsearch security is auto enabled (Didn't create any custom certs)
Can someone please help me with this, I am stuck at this point from past one week.